# How to install UTMStack Windows Agent?

Tags: windows, security, installation

I installed the UTMStack free version https://utmstack.com/install/, and I'm trying to install the Windows Agent, but I don't know how to do it. Can someone guide me?

Answer (score 0):

#### How to install UTMStack Windows Agent?

> **Graphic Installation**
>
> - Run `windows-agent-[version].exe` and follow the installation wizard.
> - Access the configuration panel through a browser, using the desktop shortcut or accessing to http://127.0.0.1:23948
> - Configure the IP of the probe to which the agent will connect in the "Settings" tab.
>
> **Installation and configuration in unattended mode**
>
> - You can install UTMStack agent in unattended mode from the command line:
>
>   windows-agent-[version].exe /verysilent /supressmsgboxes /host=IP_ADDRESS
> - Replace "IP_ADDRESS" with the address of the probe host to which the agent should send collected data.

Source: [AtlasInsideCorp/UTMStackWindowsAgent: UTMStack HIDS and logs shipper for Microsoft Windows](https://github.com/AtlasInsideCorp/UTMStackWindowsAgent)